# Change Server 2012 R2 Start Menu To A Windows 10 Start Menu

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-10

I have been looking all over for a way to get the start menu back in Server 2012 R2.  [I ran across a page that said the following](http://www.classicshell.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=5417#p23789)...

> The TH2 update (Version 1511/November 2015 Update) brings the Windows
>   10 Start Menu to Windows Server 2012 R2. Of course, if you use Classic
>   Shell, you get a far superior Start Menu.

I can not find anything that is "clear" as to how to enable the start menu again.  Does anyone know what this "TH2 update" is and how to get my start menu to show up on server 2012 r2?

Answer (score 2):

You should link the page that quote comes from because it doesn't really make much sense.  The TH2 (Threshold 2) update only applies to Windows 10.

I'm open to being wrong, but I find it hard to believe that Microsoft would back port cosmetic start menu changes from Windows 10 to Windows Server 2012 R2.  The first server OS where you'll likely get the Windows 10 style start menu is Windows Server 2016.  Windows Server 2012 R2 is the same generation/kernel as Windows 8.1 and shares its basic UI constructs like the start screen.

Comment: appears to be here: http://www.classicshell.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=5417#p23789

Comment: @tombull89 that's exactly it, thanks.  I did not want to promote products if I could avoid it.  Trying to not break any type of rules etc...  :)

Comment: @ryan So are you saying there is no way to get the start menu to show up in server 2012r2?  That was my main question.  It would just be nice if I could make it look like win 10 if that was even possible.  (I only asked about win10 because of what I read from that webpage)

Comment: There's no way I know of without 3rd party products to make clicking the start button in Windows Server 2012 R2 look like it does in Windows 10.  Again, Server 2012 R2 is just the server version of Windows 8.1 and Windows 8.1 has always had a full screen start menu (or "start screen" as some call it). You will need to wait for the server version of Windows 10 to be released which is Windows Server 2016.